# Docker: wget for https does not work

Tags: bash, shell, https, docker, wget

In my docker file I have below command

```
RUN wget -o test.jar https://bintray.com/artifact/download/thesamet/maven/gerrit-saml-plugin-2.11.4-2.jar
```

But in build I get below error:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -o test.jar https://bintray.com/artifact/download/thesamet/maven/gerrit-saml-plugin-2.11.4-2.jar' returned a non-zero code: 8
```

I tried `--no-check-certificate` and `-U` but got same error.

Comment: Is there no error message generated by `wget`? Are there spaces in the URL?

Comment: No error and the url is https://bintray.com/artifact/download/thesamet/maven/gerrit-saml-plugin-2.11.4-2.jar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below command works. I should have used ADD

```
ADD https://bintray.com/artifact/download/thesamet/maven/gerrit-saml-plugin-2.11.4-2.jar .
```

Comment: `ADD {source} {destination}`

https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-docker-add-command

Answer (score 2):

The [manual of wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Logging-and-Input-File-Options) says that `-o` specifies where log messages are written to. This mean the option `-o test.jar` causes that error messages are written to `test.jar` instead of stderr. You will not see any error messages on stderr and you will not download the file to `test.jar`.

The following command works on my pc and if any error occurs, you should see a message now:

```
wget -O test.jar https://bintray.com/artifact/download/thesamet/maven/gerrit-saml-plugin-2.11.4-2.jar
```

Comment: I get `HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2015-12-07 04:00:37 ERROR 403: Forbidden.`

Comment: @Sara this mean that the server says that you have no access to the requested path. Maybe you have a typo in your script?

Comment: I copied the same line and ran it which was successful

Comment: @Sara what does `wget` say further? Is the URL which is written out by `wget` correct?

Comment: It says `20 redirections exceeded.` becuase it trys the same command 20 times

Comment: @Sara Maybe you could show the whole output of a run of `wget`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97152/discussion-between-jojoatxgme-and-sara).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is a proxy issue.

We fixed the proxy issue by:

wget --no-check-certificate  -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=YOURPROXY http://... ...